# QSortFilterProxyModel does not return a valid index

Tags: c++, qt5, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

The following pseudo code will be used for explaining my problem:

```
QTreeView* treeView = new QTreeView();
QStandardItemModel* sourceModel = new QStandardItemModel();
//sourceModel has seven columns and will be filled here with four rows
QSortFilterProxyModel* sortFilterProxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel();

sortFilterProxyModel->setSourceModel(sourceModel);
treeView->setModel( sortFilterProxyModel );
```

Now if I call `sortFilterProxyModel->rowCount()` I get the correct value `4`. If I try to get the index of the first column in the first row from the source model it works:

```
QModelIndex idxOfFirstItem = sourceModel->index( 0, 0 );
```

Now since the user is able to sort the view I want to get the index of the first item from the proxy model:

```
QModelIndex idxOfFirstItem = sortFilterProxyModel->index( 0, 0 );
```

I always get an invalid index here no matter what the row and column is. What am I doing wrong?

**Solution:**

Ok guys. I solved the problem. Thanks to all your comments, I realized that the implementation should be right. So I tried a few other things and realized that I had a timing problem. My implementation tried to retrieve data from the model while it was still updating. So the source model of the proxy model was not valid during the update. And therefore I got no valid index. After adding a sleep the implementation worked as I need. So I have to synchronize some events in my program. Thank you for your inspiration :)

Comment: Invalid meaning `idxOfFirstItem.isValid()` returns `false` or meaning not usable with `sourceModel`?

Comment: Yes, `idxOfFirstItem.isValid()` returns `false`. I think I know what you suppose. I am not trying to access the source model items using the proxy model index. I finally want to call `sortFilterProxyModel->mapToSource(idxOfFirstItem)`. But this is not possible if I don't get a valid index from the proxy model.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice the following sentence in the QSortFilterProxyModel documentation: "The QSortFilterProxyModel acts as a wrapper for the original model. If you need to convert source QModelIndexes to sorted/filtered model indexes or vice versa, use mapToSource(), mapFromSource(), mapSelectionToSource(), and mapSelectionFromSource()." It seems you need the mapFromSource() to convert between QModelIndex of the proxy model and source model.

Comment: I checked `sortFilterProxyModel->sourceModel()->index(0,0)` returns a valid index. So the source model has been set correctly. And as I wrote in my last comment I know that the proxy model is a wrapper and I have to use the `map...` functions. But I want to map an index from the proxy model (which is the model that will be manipulated from the user by sorting the columns) to the source model. And this is not possible if I don't get the right index from the proxy model. I cannot call the `mapToSource` function with an invalid index.

Comment: By way of a quick test, what happens if you do `sortFilterProxyModel->mapFromSource(sourceModel->index(0, 0))`?  Does that result in a valid or invalid model index?